# Merging divs using their div id?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

Basically I have a total of about 19 divs that share 3 classes and 3 ids. Is there a way for me to join the 19 smaller divs and make them one larger one in relation to each of their relevant classes?

If code any code is required from me then feel free to ask, feeling like there could be a way to use either Concat with my MySQL statement or maybe something in the php.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your HTML/CSS code and provide a JSFiddle if you can.

Comment: DIVs that _share_ ids? This should be avoided. In HTML, ids are supposed to be _unique_ throughout the whole document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in javascript by grabbing their class name or their IDs. With classes it would look like this,

```
var smalldivs = document.getElementsByClassName("small-div");

var combined = "";
for(var i = 0; i < smalldivs.length; ++i){
combined = combined + smalldivs[i].innerHTML;
}

var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.innerHTML = combined;

for(var i = 0; i < smalldivs.length; ++i){
  if(i == 0){
    smalldivs[i].parentNode.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
  smalldivs[i].parentNode.removeChild(smalldivs[i]);
  i = i -1;
}
```

[Here is a jfiddle of combining divs](https://jsfiddle.net/camccar/50z1a93g/1/)

Comment: This works just fine for me. Wasn't sure if there was a simple way around it but this has me working once again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**ID's are unique**

Each element can have only one ID
Each page can have only one element with that ID

**Classes are NOT unique**

You can use the same class on multiple elements.
You can use multiple classes on the same element.

---

A little more explanation about the differences.

Maybe a good analogy here is bar codes and serial numbers. Take an iPod in a store. On the packaging will be a bar code. This tells the store what the product is, so when it is scanned, the system knows exactly what the product is and what it costs. It might even be able to know what color it is or where it was kept in the store. All iPod of this same type have the exact same bar code on them.

The iPod will also have a serial number on it which is absolutely unique to any other iPod (or any other device) in the world. The serial number doesn't know the price. It could, but for the store this wouldn't be a very efficient way to store and use that data. Much easier to use the barcode, so that for example, if the price changed, you could just change the price for that bar code and not every individual serial number in your system.

This is much like ID's and Classes. Information that is reusable should be kept in a class and information that is totally unique should be kept in an ID.

[Read more about the differences](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)